# Validation on inherited sitecore fields?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Basically I have a Sitecore Data Template Base which is used as base for a few other templates, on one specific inheriting template the fields are exactly the same however I'd like to add a field validation rule on one of the inherited fields to check the string length.

I thought about overriding the field in the template in question but I've been told that sitecore doesn't handle overriding fields?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could think about setting the validation for the field and then making use of the `Suppressed Item Validation Rules` field to suppress the validation on the templates that don't require it.  Here is a blog post that may be able to help: http://blog.velir.com/index.php/2012/11/12/suppress-validation-rules-with-base-templates/

Comment: I believe this is the only way of doing in when using inherited fields. Thanks!